# mySQL update query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this database, with these records ( I've done it just to test the UPDATE query that I will implement into my own DB )

I have a problem with the update query, but first this is how it looks like :
[image: DB]

Users table
[image: user table]

Salary table
[image: salary table]

Presence table
[image: presence table]

Department table
[image: department table]

So when I run my query I intend to modify all the records from my Salary table, based on the hours worked by my users, for now I'll not use the data column since I can't even do this basic query.
This is how my failed attempt(s) looks like:

1'st try :

```
update table salary
      set salary.sum = presence.id_presence * 5 
      FROM salary INNER JOIN users1 INNER JOIN salary WHERE id_salary = id_presence
```

2'nd try ( a suggestion ) :

```
     UPDATE salary, presence
  SET salary.sum = SUM(presence.hours) * 5
WHERE presence.id = salary.id
```

3'rd try :

UPDATE salary
  SET salary.sum = (
     SELECT SUM(presence.hours) * 5
     FROM user, presence
     WHERE presence.id = salary.id

)

I really need some help with this one, I can't understand where I am failing

Comment: when you say failing, what exactly is failing? do you get a server error or is it that you are failing to get the correct query semantics?

Comment: I guess `salariu` is only a typo here in your post, right? Just to make that sure :-) Any error messages or just not doing what you expect?

Comment: failing to get the correct query semantics, basically when I'm entering this nothing happens.

Comment: It's a typo made in my post, not in my query, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working thanks to a great guy

answer :

```
UPDATE salary
  SET sum = (
     SELECT SUM(presence.hours) * 5
     FROM user, presence
     WHERE presence.id = salary.id
  )
```

Comment: If that's the query it won't work, because of the trailing `AND`. But probably a typo again. Please update :-)

Comment: Sorry, It's late for my so I'm doing lots of mistakes. I've tested the query and everything works smoothly. I just need to judge a filter for my salaries, this mode is way to simple 

UPDATE salary
  SET sum = (
     SELECT SUM(presence.hours) * 5
     FROM user, presence
     WHERE presence.id = salary.id
     AND   <some filter on the month that depends on salary.date>
  )

Comment: Ah, ok. Is the filter part a question? It's late for me to and my beer does the rest.

Comment: Nah, I'll make  a separate question related to that one, because I have no clue how to make the filter. I only know that I need to apply the query each 30 days and calculate the precise salary/ user